# Symfony "no PHP binaries detected" on GNU / Linux Debian

Tags: symfony

I'm installing Symfony framework following the instructions of https://symfony.com/download using symfony-cli.

When I executed

```
  symfony new my_symfony_app
```

I get the next Error

```
  no PHP binaries detected
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the solution would be to install php by using apt, but after some research I read about php-symfony deb package and I installed it.

```
apt install php-symfony
```

Works fine to me and solved the problem.